# I want to ignore a "file" from my XCode project using Git

Tags: xcode, git

I'm starting to use Git and for this project one file is appearing when I use git status.

[image]

I couldn't add it in .ignore file.

There is any way to not have when I use git status?

Comment: Why can't you add it to .gitignore? (also, why haven't you added .gitignore to your repo?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

The *.gitglobalignores* file in my home directory includes these lines:

```
xcuserdata
project.xcworkspace
```

Go ye and do likewise, and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you've already committed the `xcuserstate` file, so it doesn't matter whether you add it to `.gitignore`. You need to remove it from the repo to make it be ignored in the future. You should also add the `.gitignore` file.

```
git rm -r --cached Quizzler.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
git add .gitignore
git commit
```